# Что значит "пустой" return?

Tags: java

Пример кода:

```
final List<Item> items = tableView.getItems();
if (items == null || items.size() == 0) return;
```

Что в данном случае возвращает `return`?

Метод целиком:

```
void refreshTable() {
    final List<Item> items = tableView.getItems();
    if (items == null || items.size() == 0) return;
    final Item item = tableView.getItems().get(0);
    items.remove(0);
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            items.add(0, item);
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: возвращаемое значение метода у вас `void` и `return` ничего не возвращает, а используется просто для досрочного выхода из метода.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если метод возвращает `void`, то чтобы закончить работу не доходя до конца метода, можно вызвать пустой `return` там, где Вы хотите закончить работу.

В конкретном, Вашем, примере `return` вызывается при условии, что список `items` пустой.